# What evolutionary pressures would lead to Oni?

Tags: science-based, biology, evolution, fantasy-races

among the many races in my world include Oni and i'm curious as to what evolutionary pressures would to a group of divergent hominids to evolve into them? some basic characteristics of my Oni are:

- range in height from 6 to 7 feet tall
- males have horns
- have bright red faces (similar to the [Bald uakaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bald_uakari))
- are as intelligent as humans
- have an improved sense of smell
- are stronger
- are slower and have slightly worse endurance
- are less fertile
- can interbreed with humans

Note: Magic does not exist in my story

Comment: What kind of environment do these demons live in?

Comment: @JMERICKS originally in east asia but later migrated to other parts of the world

Comment: Whats the time period more or less?

Comment: @JMERICKS i'd say at most around 250,000 years ago but i don't know if that's enough time for the changes i want

Comment: besides the name my question and the anatomically correct one share little resemblance to each other, so i don't get why mine's considered a duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Humans lost the ability to evolve from environmental pressure the moment they invented homes and clothing, the same would happen for any intelligent species.

The only thing driving human evolution now is sexual selection, economy and viruses, and it has been like that for the past 12'000 years.

- range in height from 6 to 7 feet tall

In human societies taller people are and have always been seen as sexier

- males have horns

Females have a horn fetish the same way peacocks have a tail fetish

- have bright red faces (similar to the Bald uakaris)

Sun exposure turns your skin red if you were born with low melanin building potential, my skin gets red not black from sun bathing...and red in a healthy way not burned red...this happens to most of the people from my ethnicity

- are as intelligent as humans

Many people are as intelligent as humans, but not all people, it depends on the country...in countries like niger for example the average IQ is below 80 and in China it is above 100

- have an improved sense of smell

Smelling pheromones and hormones is usefull in the sex game

- are stronger

Polish and Scandinavian people are on average 1.7 to 2.3 stronger than africans, does that count as being a devil?

- are slower and have slightly worse endurance

South africans are more enduring than northerner humans, does that make them non devils?

- are less fertile

You need magic for that, pandas are like that and they survived by  the pity of humans forcing them to have sex or forcing them to watch pornography...like...just let those emos go extinct!

- can interbreed with humans

Dragon men, Denisovans and Neanderthals could and did interbreed with sapiens, the definition of species is a loose and futile one.